# Is adb exec-out ok for production use? Why is it hidden?

Tags: android, adb

The `adb exec-out` subcommand is with us for years. I've never had any issues with it.
The only problem I have is that I don't feel comfortable using it in production scripts
as it is undocumented.

Should I treat that as an unofficial/undocumented that should be avoided?
Why is it somehow hidden feature of adb?

I understand that `adb longcat` or `adb lolcat` are hidden and can be treated as an easter egg, but exec-out is very useful and less security error prone.

The main difference between `adb shell` vs. `adb exec-out` is more or less like
`subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)` vs. `subprocess.run(cmd, shell=False)` in python.

Clearly, the `shell=True` should be used only when really needed (redirections, pipe to other command, command sequences, background process, etc.).

For typical usage "run this command with this argument" the exec-out seems to be more valid and I believe this should be even default way to go unless you need a shell.